# unable to split ZipFile.namelist() paths

Tags: python, split

`zipfile.ZipFile.namelist()` returns filepaths with single backslashes like this:

```
>>> p = "\mode\Revoke\CardWithValidQc_SunshineRevoke\19CD1C21.htm"
>>> p.split("\\")
['mode', 'Revoke', 'CardWithValidQc_SunshineRevoke\x019CD1C21.htm']
```

How can I split the `\x`?

Comment: \x is an escape character. It is actually "\x01". Please provide the exact output from zipfile, because your first line (p = "...") should have been p = r"...".

Comment: You only wrote the string literal in the first line in a wrong way. Just prefix the string with `r`. "namelist" isn't affected by this.